# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController issue. How to show only contacts with emails?

Tags: iphone, ios, abpeoplepickerview

Is there any way to provide the screen, where user can see only contacts than contains emails? (because by default I see all contacts on this screen)

```
 ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    // place the delegate of the picker to the controll
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;

    // showing the picker
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    // releasing
    [picker release];
```

Then I want to pick up the selected emails.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is a way to get iOS to do this filtering. Note that you need to look for all kinds of email addresses - you have to iterate through the dictionary that you can get. Working with this is a PITA for sure and you have to be careful to not have memory leaks.

Comment: to iterate I need to get all contacts, but I can get the contact only when user selects it. So how can I iterate through all contacts?